# how to repeat a string with number for certain replicate

Tags: r

I want to repeat a string for several times

```
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep1
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep2
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
rep3
```

I want to repeat this until 8000 lines

I know how to repeat a string but I could not figure out how to make it with number and how to do it for a certain number of lines

I can do this and then merge them

```
a <- rep("rep1", 12)
b <- rep("rep2", 12)
c <- rep("rep3", 12)
df <- rbind(a,b)
df <- rbind(df, c)
```

but how can I have it for as many lines as I want ?

Comment: Do you want "re1" as in the example text or "rep1" as in the example code?

Comment: Helps to be consistent if you want people to understand your question.

Comment: @neilfws that is great I want to repeat that until I have 8000 lines , this gives me only 36 lines

Comment: @Ronak Shah no, just rep1 rep2 rep3 each 12 times and it generates until 8000 lines

Comment: @Ronak Shah it will produce rep1, rep2, rep3 , rep1......

Comment: @Ronak Shah please check my question. rep1 is repeated 12 times, rep2 repeated 12 times, rep3 repeated 12 times, then rep1 should be repeated 12 time, then rep2 should be repeated 12 times then rep3 should be reaped 12 times .....

Comment: @Ronak Shah YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `rep` again.

```
rep(c(a,b,c), 8000/36+1)[1:8000]
```

Or using the comment of @RonakShah

```
rep(c(a,b,c), length.out=8000)
```

Comment: it gives me `rep(c("a","b","c"), length.out=12)
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"`  I want to  `rep1 is repeated 12 times, rep2 repeated 12 times, rep3 repeated 12 times, then rep1 should be repeated 12 time, then rep2 should be repeated 12 times then rep3 should be reaped 12 times`

Comment: I did not write `rep(c("a","b","c")`.   I wrote `rep(c(a,b,c)`  Get rid of the quotes.

Comment: @G5W I get error `rep(c(a,b,c), length.out=8000)
Error: object 'a' not found`

Comment: You must run the code that you included in your example. `a <- rep("rep1", 12)
`